# Div disable in mobil

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make div with custom id or class don't load add all in mobile screen.
The CSS
 display:none; 
don't help me. I need the code don't load add all. 
thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i say the display:none its not a way for me. thanks for reply

Comment: Media Queries are the solution. `display:none` doesn't have to be part of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: thank you for time time. I cant understand how can i "disable" a div in mobile with this. disable not hide it

Comment: Set up a media query that detects the mobile screen. Then you can use the `matchMedia` JavaScript method from my second link to set up an `if/else` statement the enables or disables the element.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are seeking **media query** which helps to change properities of elements based on screen resolution...